# Rename images on FTP Folder with different Names(Timestamp) to One File and delete others

Tags: php, ftp, rename, delete-file

I have a Webcam that Uploads Pictures to a FTP Folder every 5 minutes.

Unfortunaly the Webcam upload each file with different name (192.168.1.150xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg).

xxxxxxxxxxxxxx stands for a Timestamp from the Webcam.

I tried to make a php script to rename the jpg to another name.
I do not know the code to delete the old image.

I want to run it with cron job on my host server every 6 minutes so that i would have a stable name like meteotimb.jpg.

I have this script till now:

```html
<?php
$fileList = glob('192*.jpg');
var_dump($fileList);
foreach (glob("192*.jpg") as $filename) {
  echo "Renaming " . $filename . " now.</br>";
  $uniqid = uniqid();
  if(file_exists($filename)) {
    rename($filename, "meteotimb" . $uniqid . ".jpg");
    echo $filename . " is now meteotimb" . $uniqid . ".jpg</br>";
  }
}
?>
```

So when the cron job runs it rename all the images that starts with 192 to meteotimb5846cv895.jpg, meteotimb5896sjv845.jpg etc

I do not know why this 5846cv895 appear on name.

I also do not know what code shall i use to delete all the 192. files after the rename. and i want only one meteotimb.jpg to remain the last one from timestamp.

Any help?

Comment: Did you read the docs for `uniqid()` before you used it?

Answer (score 0):

unlink($file_name) function deletes a file. Regarding "5846cv895 appear on name" try replacing

```
rename($filename, "meteotimb" . $uniqid . ".jpg");
```

with

```
rename($filename, '"meteotimb" . $uniqid . ".jpg"');
```

note the single quotes added in 2nd parameter.